# Work around to make table-cell CSS render properly in IE6/7?

Tags: html, css, styling, css-tables

My site is showing up fine in IE8/Firefox/Chrome but I can't figure out how to make it function with IE.

The relevant CSS:

```
#maincontent {  
  display: table;   
}  

#content {  
  display: table-cell;  
  width: 620px;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-right: 22px; 
  padding-bottom:15px;  
} 

#sidebar { 
  display: table-cell;  
  width: 300px; 
}
```

`#content` and `#sidebar` are in `#maincontent`. On IE6/7 `#sidebar` will be under `#content`. I've tried setting the sidebar to `display:block` with a `float`, and it will then render fine in IE6/7 but all the other browsers get screwed up. How can I get this setup?

Answer (score 3):

From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp):

> No versions of Internet Explorer
>   (including IE8) support the property
>   values "inline-table", "run-in",
>   "table", "table-caption",
>   "table-cell", "table-column",
>   "table-column-group", "table-row", or
>   "table-row-group".

The best solution is probably to build a real table.

Comment: Provided that whatever it contains is semantically tabular data. If your intent was merely to provide table-like layout for non-tabular elements, then you'll want to continue to explore non-table-based methods.

Comment: Good point. I shouldn't have made the assumption it was a data table.

Comment: W3Schools is not affiliated with the W3C and has a reputation for incorrect or poorly explained information. See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display#compatibilitysection for accurate information

Answer (score 1):

CSS tables aren't supported in IE, so you'll probably want to try working with just floats and margins.  I'd recommend taking a look at the positioning on [one of these templates](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C9/) and working from there.