# IE6 CSS display:table fix?

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-6

I'm working on a web app... unfortunately it has to work with the worst piece of software ever written, yes ie6.

I really like the CSS `display:table` and `display:table-cell` properties, but of course it doesn't work in ie.

Has anyone found any fixes for this? I have been looking, but haven't found anything.
Conditional CSS, .htc files, javascript...anything?
I would really like to avoid making everything with floats and clears

Comment: Maybe with CSS pie? http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Is this for layout, or actual tabular data which would be sensible to just put in `<table>` and related elements?

Comment: Layout, I'm talking about CSS property display:table, not html table

Comment: I found this http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ and it looks great. Many things fixed, but I can't find the property I'm looking for. Anyone tried this script?

Comment: It seems like there is no fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327046/work-around-to-make-table-cell-css-render-properly-in-ie6-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry. There isn't a fix to make IE6 support CSS `display:table`. The only way to acheive this layout in IE6 is to actually use `<table>` elements.

First question: do you really need to support IE6? If you can simply drop support for it, you'll solve yourself a whole ton of problems, including this one. Current global usage of IE6 is below 3%, and even lower in most developed countries.

If you do still need to support IE6, then your most obvious solution is simply to swallow your semantic markup pride and just use a `<table>` tag.

As described by @Tom, the next best solution is to write your layout using `display:inline-block;`.

`inline-block` allows you to define your elements as blocks, but still keep them in the text flow (kinda the way the `<img>` tag works by default). If you combine this with fixed element widths, and wapper divs around rows, you could acheive something similar to a table, although it may be hard to get it to expand dynamically with the page width.

The one big "gotcha" bug around this is that `inline-block` only works in IE6/7 for elements that have a default style of `display:inline`. In other words, it works for a `<span>` but not for a `<div>`. Not a disaster, but something to be aware of, especially since you're specifically asking about IE6 support. Other than that, the good news is that you should be able to get away with using `display:inline-block` without any other hacks or work-arounds.

Comment: unfortunately i have to support ie, not my decision... personally i would drop it without hesitation... second thing, i don't think your statistics are valid, a few years ago ie was around 50%... i really don't think it has dropped so low... unfortunately there are still many people with xp installed, who don't event know what a browser is, and use ie6 as default... sad, but true

Comment: regarding your workaround solution, i think ill just stick with floats, given ie limitations with inline-block

Comment: @ZolaKt - IE **as a whole** is still around 45%, but IE6 usage is dropping off a cliff. No stats site is ever going to be truly accurate, but for a good picture of the general trend, I recommend http://gs.statcounter.com/. They currently show IE6 at 4% worldwide, and 1.9% in Europe and 2.1% in N.America. Others show similar stats. But that's arbitrary; you need to pay attention to *your* site's usage. If you've still got enough IE6 users to make it worth supporting them, then you should do it. Really, it's a cost decision: how much does it cost to support IE6 vs how many users you'd lose.

Comment: Thanks for the stats. Anyway, generally IE6-IE9 is crap, and requires hacks and fixes to work like all the others. So if I have to hack to get it working, I might as well hack for IE6

Comment: @Spudley, love your comment: "how much does it cost to support IE6 vs how many users you'd lose". That question can/should be applied to so many things.

Answer (score 0):

IE does not support display:table and display:table-cell but IE7 and below do support display:inline-block. The common way to make this work is by doing the following:

```
display:-moz-inline-stack;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
```

Keep in mind that CSS gives you a lot of positioning power and given some context of how you want your layout to look I might be able to give you a better solution.

Due to misunderstanding let me clarify the code above.
display:-moz-inline-stack; is declared for older versions of Firefox.
zoom:1; IE has a property called [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html), this is a way to trigger it.
*display:inline is known as a *property hack used to hide this line from all **non-IE** browsers

The zoom:1 and *display:inline effectively allow block level elements to behave like inline elements (so that inline-block will work in IE6+)

For more information please read:

1. http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/
2. http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/

Comment: A good general answer, but the specific advice is somewhat out-of-date. `-moz-inline-stack` isn't necessary unless you need to support Firefox less than v2, which means you really don't need it. You don't need `*display:inline;` either, as that's overriding `inline-block` in IE6. IE6/7 do support `inline-block` (albeit with some 'gotcha' bugs); the `*display:inline` would only be needed to support IE5.5. And `zoom:1` is a common bugfix for various IE issues, but doesn't have any effect at all on `inline-block`, so I don't know why it's mentioned here.

Comment: Note: inline-block is supported on elements that are inline by default. It won't work on block elements as div in IE6.

Comment: @Spudley if IE6 support is required then I mad the assumption that older versions of Firefox would also be required.

Comment: @Spudley "You don't need *display:inline; either, as that's overriding inline-block in IE6." is very incorrect statement.