# anyone has a solution for display: table and display: table-row for IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Anyone has a solution for `display: table` and `display: table-row` for IE6?

this is my css code:

```css
.menu {
    display: table;
    width: 708px;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    z-index:99;
}

.menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.menu li a.mainnav{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Is it IE6 commemoration day or something? There has been a spike in questions about IE6 being posted today.

Comment: @BoltClock don't know but this browser is a pain to all developers :(

Comment: Not to the ones who boldly refuse to support it. You might lose your job, but you'll keep your honor. ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock There's life in the old dog yet >.<

Comment: You could use an actual table? :)

Comment: @BoltClock - that would imply it had died which is sadly not the case. Not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I could find two possible answers.

One [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327903/ie6-css-displaytable-fix) at stackoverflow.

And other is kind of a dirty [hack](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/)

Comment: I tried to use the second option but somehow i can't refer the .htc right, i tried to include it on the root and make the right direction and still not working, if you can help me in this, it would be great.

Comment: @HaiderGhaleb Does your server send [`Content-Type: text/x-component`](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/#h-server) response-header for `htc` files? Could you provide a live example?