# Responsive layout with horizontally centered fixed width and height DIVs

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I'm trying to achieve the following result. I would like to build a responsive layout where I can display on a row a number of DIVs (kind of boxes or tiles) **of fixed width and height** that drop on the row below when the browser is resized. The group of 'tiles' should be always centered in the browser window but the single tiles should be aligned to the left when dropped on the row below. **The layout should be compatible with IE6 and above.**

My main problem is with IE 6 and 7 (don't know 8) because the DIV (`.container`) that contains the group of tiles is set up as `display: table` which I know is not supported by IE6+. I know there's a workaround with a .HTC file but I'm pretty sure there is a better solution. I don't worry using JQuery if needed or pure CSS.

[image: Responsive layout]

With `media queries` I set the `.container` width according to the browser size

```
@media (min-width: 1110px) {
    .container{
        width: 1100px;
    }
}
```

This works but not in IE

```
.container {
    display:table;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.box {
   float: left;
   background: #CECECE;
   height: 200px;
   width: 150px;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

**I would like to use this same layout on mobile devices too so that when the device is rotated the 'tiles' move accordingly.**

Comment: "IE6 and above" - you have to be joking. IE 6 is used by 0.2% in US and 0.5% in Europe. Zero Point Two percent! :) Idk. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327903/ie6-css-displaytable-fix - but as miro said I would definitely sunset IE6 & IE7 support and only worry about IE8 (as long as XP is around).

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite what you asked for, but it's close, and does work in IE6 (and kind of looks better, IMHO):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

.wrap {width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;}

.col1 {width: 49.5%; float: left;}

.col2 {width: 49.5%; float: right;}

.col1 div, .col2 div {width: 150px; height: 200px; background: #ccc;}

.col1 div {float: right; margin: 0 0 2% 2%;}

.col2 div {float: left; margin: 0 2% 2% 0;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="col1">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very pretty and elegant. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you like it. :-) I'm not good enough to go the next step and do what you asked for in IE6, although I'll bet it's doable. Like many others, I've fully eschewed IE6 and 7.